# using the proper google map listener

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map that I am building. 
I have a listener on it:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function(ev){
    plotzips();
});
```

The function on the inside calls for a kml:

```
var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(url, {
    suppressInfoWindows: false,  
    map:map,
    zindex: 0,
    clickable : false
});
```

Now.  Whenever there's a movement on the map done by a user, the kml refreshes. 
This part works.

The problem is that it works too well.  the trigger 'idle' works also during the refresh when the kml loads.  How do I use the trigger ONLY when a user moves the map?

Thanks

Comment: `center_changed` or `bounds_changed` events will fire when the map moves or is zoomed.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) (check the section under "Events") states that the '*idle*' event is "fired when the map becomes idle after panning or zooming," I (like you) have found that it also fires for other things.

You might have better luck with the '*dragend*' event. Check the "Events" section on the "Map" class [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map). To get the precise behavior you're looking for, you may need to bind to multiple events. For example, you may also wish to bind '*zoom_changed*' to load KML data on map zoom in or out.